# A template as a template parameter in a play 2 views

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I would like to define some templates in play 2 which takes an other template as a parameter:

```
@aTemplate(otherTemplate())
```

I think that should be possible in scala, right?

How would look like the parameter definition in the `otherTemplate()`? I should also have a default value in it. I'm thinking of something like that:

```
@(template: PlayScalaViewTemplate = defaultTemplate())
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. It's very simple once you discover that Play templates are just functions.

The higher order template (the one that gets the simple template as parameter) would look like this:

**higherOrder.scala.html:**

```
@(template: Html => Html)

<html>
    <head><title>Page</title></head>
<body>
    @template {
        <p>This is rendered within the template passed as parameter</p>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

So, if you have a simple sub-template like

**simple.scala.html:**

```
@(content: Html)

<div>
    <p>This is the template</p>
    @content
</div>
```

you would apply the template in the controller like so:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.higherOrder(html => views.html.simple(html)))
}
```

The result would be:

```
<html>
<head><title>Page</title></head>
<body>


<div>
    <p>This is the template</p>

    <p>This is rendered within the template passed as parameter</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, scala templates are ultimately functions so you can compose them like functions.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I found the `Html` parameter type too but how could I define a default "function"/`content: Html` for simple.scala.html?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Templates generate classes that have an `apply` method which receive the arguments required by the template.